# Dataframe - Create new column based on a given column's previous & current row value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am dealing with a dataframe which has several thousands of rows & has several columns. The column of interest is called `customer_csate_score`.

The data looks like below

```
customer_csate_score
    0.000
    -0.4
    0
    0.578
    0.418
    -0.765
    0.89
```

What I'm trying to do is create a new column in the dataframe called `customer_csate_score_toggle_status` which will have true if the value changed either from a positive value to a negative value or vice-versa. It will have value false if the polarity didn't reverse.

**Expected Output for toggle status column**

```
 customer_csate_score_toggle_status
        False
        True
        False
        True
        False
        True
        True
```

I've tried few different things but haven't been able to get this to work. Here's what I've tried -

**Attempt - 1**

```
   def update_cust_csate_polarity(curr_val, prev_val):
        return True if (prev_val <= 0 and curr_val > 0) or  (prev_val >= 0 and curr_val < 0) else False
    
    data['customer_csate_score_toggle_status'] = data.apply(lambda x: update_cust_csate_polarity(data['customer_csate_score'], data['customer_csate_score'].shift()))
```

**Attempt - 2**

```
//Testing just one condition
    data['customer_csate_score_toggle_status'] = data[(data['customer_csate_score'].shift() < 0) & (data['customer_csate_score']) > 0]
```

Could I please request help to get this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the sign change using `np.sign(df.customer_csate_score)[lambda x: x != 0].diff() != 0`:

1. Get the sign of values;
2. Filter out 0s so sequence like `5 0 1` won't get marked incorrectly;
3. Check if the sign has changed using `diff`.

---

```
import numpy as np
df['customer_csate_score_toggle_status'] = np.sign(df.customer_csate_score)[lambda x: x != 0].diff() != 0
df['customer_csate_score_toggle_status'] = df['customer_csate_score_toggle_status'].fillna(False)

df
   customer_csate_score  customer_csate_score_toggle_status
0                 0.000                               False
1                -0.400                                True
2                 0.000                               False
3                 0.578                                True
4                 0.418                               False
5                -0.765                                True
6                 0.890                                True
```

Comment: Brilliant stuff. Thanks a million. Would've never ever thought of an inbuilt function in numpy for this. Please could you tell me what is this piece of code for - df['customer_csate_score_toggle_status'] = df['customer_csate_score_toggle_status'].fillna(False)

Comment: I actually run fillna(True) as part of cleaning up the dataframe before running any code against it. Bad idea?

Comment: It's  filling `False` back to where originally 0s are, since we removed 0s in previous step in order  to calculate the change.

Comment: *I actually run fillna(True) as part of cleaning up the dataframe*. It depends on why you would need to fill the values. I think it's unrelated to what we are doing here. So I wouldn't just say it's a bad idea.

Comment: Actually this solution fills True against NaN. How could I write False against NaN?

Comment: IIUC, you can prefill NaN with 0s with `.fillna(0)` or filter it out  in the filter step `[lambda x: (x != 0) && x.notnull()]`

Comment: Sorry for being a pain. ```[lambda x: (x != 0) && x.notnull()]``` threw syntax errors. Changed it to ```[lambda x: (x != 0) & x.notnull()]```. Although the code executes, it still shows True instead of false. I also tried ```df.fillna(0, inplace=True)```. Even with this, the toggle value still is true. Please anyway to change this to False? I would be scanning the dataframe  for True only on this column at some point. So, having True where it is not really true in the sense I mean it will make things complicated.

Comment: Oops, sorry about  the syntax error, glad you figure  it out  yourself. Hmm hard to tell without seeing the actual data. Can you provide a minimal example (maybe in another question since it looks like there are some cases this question doesn't cover) ?

Comment: I've created a new question for another piece of functionality I'm looking to implement. Please could you help? Question is here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69086986/dataframe-create-new-column-based-on-condition