# Dataframe - Create new column based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am dealing with a dataframe which has several thousands of rows & has several columns. The columns of interest is called `customer_csate_score` & `group_csate_score`

The data looks like below

```
customer_csate_score group_csate_score
    0.000                   -0.15
    -0.4                     0.12
    0                        0.13 
    0.578                    0.81   
    0.418                    0.96
    -0.765                   0.1
    0.89                     -0.87
```

What I'm trying to do is create 2 new columns in the dataframe called `customer_group_csate_score_toggle_status` & `is_customer_perf_above_group_perf`. `customer_group_csate_score_toggle_status` will be true only when `customer_csate_score` &
`group_csate_score` cross over & False when there is no crossover. `is_customer_perf_above_group_perf`  is True if `customer_csate_score` is above
`group_csate_score` & False if `customer_csate_score` is below
`group_csate_score`

**Expected Output for toggle status column**

```
 customer_group_csate_score_toggle_status  is_customer_perf_above_group_perf
        False                                        True
        True                                         False
        False                                        False
        False                                        False
        False                                        False
        False                                        False
        True                                         True
```

I've tried this code so far -

```
def check_cust_group_crossover(df, df_key1, def_key2):
    return np.where(
        (
            (df[df_key1] > df[def_key2]) & \
            (df[df_key1].shift() < df[def_key2].shift())
        ),
        True, False
    )
```

I'm struggling to implement the entire functionality. Could I please request guidance to implement this?

Comment: It would help if you could provide a **minimal** working example with sample data and easier (shorter) variable/column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set boolean masks for the crossover conditions.  As there are 2 possible crossover cases, we `or` them to get the final conditions for `customer_group_csate_score_toggle_status`

For `is_customer_perf_above_group_perf` just compare whether `customer_csate_score` > `group_csate_score`:

```
m1 = (df['customer_csate_score'] > df['group_csate_score']) & (df['customer_csate_score'].shift() < df['group_csate_score'].shift())  
m2 = (df['customer_csate_score'] < df['group_csate_score']) & (df['customer_csate_score'].shift() > df['group_csate_score'].shift())  
df['customer_group_csate_score_toggle_status'] = m1 | m2

df['is_customer_perf_above_group_perf'] = df['customer_csate_score'] > df['group_csate_score']
```

Note:  We don't need special handling ***for the first row*** for the mask on checking the previous row.  It will always return **`False`** when comparing either `(df['customer_csate_score'].shift() < df['group_csate_score'].shift())` or `(df['customer_csate_score'].shift() > df['group_csate_score'].shift())` for the first row since we are comparing `NaN` with `NaN`.  Hence comparing (`NaN` > `NaN`) or  (`NaN` < `NaN`) will always return `False` as expected.

**Result**:

```
print(df)

   customer_csate_score  group_csate_score  customer_group_csate_score_toggle_status  is_customer_perf_above_group_perf
0                 0.000              -0.15                                     False                               True
1                -0.400               0.12                                      True                              False
2                 0.000               0.13                                     False                              False
3                 0.578               0.81                                     False                              False
4                 0.418               0.96                                     False                              False
5                -0.765               0.10                                     False                              False
6                 0.890              -0.87                                      True                               True
```

Comment: Thank you very much @SeaBean. This works for me. Also, a huge thank you for the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can first compute "is_customer_perf_above_group_perf", which is a simple comparison of the initial two columns. Then compute the `diff` on the new column, which will be True when the value changes (i.e., when there is "crossing"). This `fillna(False)` is to set the first value as it has no previous row to compare with.

```
(df.eval('is_customer_perf_above_group_perf = customer_csate_score > group_csate_score')
   .assign(customer_group_csate_score_toggle_status=lambda d: d['is_customer_perf_above_group_perf'].diff().fillna(False))
)
```

output:

```
   customer_csate_score  group_csate_score  is_customer_perf_above_group_perf  customer_group_csate_score_toggle_status
0                 0.000              -0.15                               True                                     False
1                -0.400               0.12                              False                                      True
2                 0.000               0.13                              False                                     False
3                 0.578               0.81                              False                                     False
4                 0.418               0.96                              False                                     False
5                -0.765               0.10                              False                                     False
6                 0.890              -0.87                               True                                      True
```

Comment: Thank you very much @mozway. This works well.